# loop all rows in csv array with python error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

i have this csv array:

```
number,event_date,event_timestamp,event_name,event_params
0,20220315,1668314165054758,eventTracking1,"[{'key': 'test0', 'value': {'string_value': None1, 'int_value': 1662354225, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
 {'key': 'test2', 'value': {'string_value': 'http:\test1.com', 'int_value': None, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
 {'key': 'test3', 'value': {'string_value': 'A@gmail.com', 'int_value': None, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}]"
1,20220325,1668445654758556,eventTracking2,"[{'key': 'test5', 'value': {'string_value': None3, 'int_value': 16658884225, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
 {'key': 'test7', 'value': {'string_value': 'http:\test2.com', 'int_value': None, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
 {'key': 'test8', 'value': {'string_value': 'A@gmail.com', 'int_value': None, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}]"
2,20220335,1668317775054758,eventTracking3,"[{'key': 'test10', 'value': {'string_value': None5, 'int_value': 1662454225, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
 {'key': 'test12', 'value': {'string_value': 'http:\test3.com', 'int_value': None, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}
 {'key': 'test13', 'value': {'string_value': 'A@gmail.com', 'int_value': None, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}]"
```

what i want to have is

```
number,event_date,event_timestamp,event_name,event_params1,event_params2
0,20220315,1668314165054758,eventTracking1,test0,None1
0,20220315,1668314165054758,eventTracking1,test2,http:\test1.com
0,20220315,1668314165054758,eventTracking1,test3,A@gmail.com
1,20220325,1668445654758556,eventTracking2,test6,None4
1,20220325,1668445654758556,eventTracking2,test7,http:\test2.com
1,20220325,1668445654758556,eventTracking2,test8,A@gmail.com
2,20220335,1668317775054758,eventTracking3,test10,None5
2,20220335,1668317775054758,eventTracking3,test12,http:\test3.com
2,20220335,1668317775054758,eventTracking3,test13,A@gmail.com
```

i have this Python code to run on csv file above. But the Code doesn't loop through all the rows, it reads the row 2 instead of row 0,1 and 2. i am newbie with python, i have tried to fix it. but i couldn't
Can you please help?
Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import re
# >>> re.sub(r'([A-Z])(?!$)', r'\1,', 'ABC')
df = pd.read_csv("check.csv")
print(df)
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
# It will take the list/dict from the relevant column
dc = df.event_params.iloc[i]
print(dc)

# The list is actually a string so we need to you eval
# Before the eval we need to fix the dict by adding comma after }}
r = re.sub("}}", r"}},", dc)
ev = eval(r)

# To get the number and event_date I just taking the column value
number = df.number.iloc[i]
event_date = df.event_date.iloc[i]
event_timestamp = df.event_timestamp.iloc[i]
event_name = df.event_name.iloc[i]

# Now lets loop over the dict and get the needed values
event_params1 = []
event_params2 = []

for i in ev:
    print(i['value'])
    print(i.keys())
    event_params1.append(i['key'])
    event_params2.append(i['value']['string_value'])


# Now creating final dataFrame and inserting all the values
df_final = pd.DataFrame()

df_final['event_params1'] = event_params1
df_final['event_params2'] = event_params2
df_final['number'] = number
df_final['event_date'] = event_date
df_final['event_timestamp'] = event_timestamp
df_final['event_name'] = event_name
df_final = df_final[['number', 'event_date', 'event_timestamp', 'event_name', 'event_params1', 
'event_params2']]

print(df_final)

# Save as csv
df_final.to_csv("This_is_what_you_nees.csv")
```

Comment: please show your code, so we can help you

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: i have added the Code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way you could do it that makes use of some regular expressions and pandas' [Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and [DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) functions

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv("check.csv")

key_regex = r"(?<=(\'key\': ))[^,]*(?=,)"
val_regex = r"(?<=(\'string_value\': ))[^,]*(?=,)"

def get_keys(x):
    return [re.search(key_regex, line).group().replace("'", "") for line in x.split("\n")]

def get_vals(x):
    return [re.search(val_regex, line).group().replace("'", "") for line in x.split("\n")]

df["event_params1"] = df["event_params"].apply(get_keys)
df["event_params2"] = df["event_params"].apply(get_vals)
del df["event_params"]

final_df = df.explode(["event_params1", "event_params2"])

print(final_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in range(3):
   print(i)
# It will take the list/dict from the relevant column
dc = df.event_params.iloc[i]
print(dc)
```

"dc = df.event_params.iloc[i]" line in your code above is no indentation, the correct syntax is:

```py
for i in range(3):
   print(i)
   # It will take the list/dict from the relevant column
   dc = df.event_params.iloc[i]
   print(dc)
```